# How does the device behind a Trendnet TEW-647GA get an IP?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Trendnet TEW-647GA. I can't figure out if it has its own DHCP server? All the manual discusses is how the Trendnet device itself gets an IP from my router, but it doesn't explain how the device plugged in to the Trendnet gets an IP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out if my Trendnet TEW-647GA has its own DHCP server.

Looking at the [manual for the Trendnet TEW-647GA (V1)](http://downloads.trendnet.com/TEW-647GA/manual/EN_Web_TEW-647GA(V1).pdf), under "Installation Requirements" on page 3, the device needs a:

> - Wireless router (e.g. TEW-639GR)
> - An available DHCP server -- wireless routers usually have a built-in DHCP server.

So the answer appears to be no, it does not have its own DHCP server.

> The manual doesn't explain how the device plugged in to the Trendnet gets an IP.

Any devices connected to the Trendnet would (apparently) obtain their IPs from the primary DHCP server (e.g. the router).

Comment: I did some more playing around - the device behind the Trendnet seems to get an IP appropriately if I configure the Trendnet to use my router's DHCP server. However, if I set a static IP on the Trendnet, the device behind the Trendnet does not seem to get an IP.